# Can't image what it must've been like to

Tags: word-usage

[image]

> Can't imagine what it must've been like to fly.

Or

> I couldn't imagine what it must 've been like to grow up with him for a father.

What's the function of "must" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the Lexico [definitions](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/must) is

> **must<sup>1</sup>**
>   MODAL VERB
>
> **2** Expressing an opinion about something that is logically very likely.
>   *There must be something wrong with people who can do cryptic crosswords.*

The phrase "can't imagine" means trying to put oneself in somebody else's position, but being unable. It is almost a contradiction though: the speaker has tried to do that and actually does have some idea what it is / was like, but not exactly.

So the sentence

> Can't imagine what it must've been like to fly.

is expressing difficulty in understanding the experience of flying but it was probably wonderful.

The sentence

> I couldn't imagine what it must've been like to grow up with him for a father.

is saying it was probably a terrible experience being raised by that man.